# React Component use the first element props instead of his own when calling a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I've trying to call a component's function but when I do it so, it overrides the parameters and passes the first array element props instead of the one that is selected.

I'm going to demonstrate better with a piece of code:

First of all this is the way I render my components list:

```
const HomeSections = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(AppContext)
  const { HomeSections: SectionData } = state.Something
  
  return (
    <aside>
      <div>
        {SectionData.map(({ title, description, imgUrl, identifier }) => {
          return (
            <Section
              title={title}
              description={description}
              imgUrl={imgUrl}
              key={identifier}
              id={identifier}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </aside>
  )
}

export default HomeSections;
```

This is my component:

```
const Section = ({ title, description, imgUrl, id }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useContext(AppContext)
  const { register, setValue } = useForm()
  setValue('title', title)
  setValue('description', description)

  const doSomething = (identifier) => {
    // Here is where the id gets overwritten by the first in the array
  }

  return (
    <div className="SomethingSection__Container">
      <input
        className="hidden"
        type="file"
        id="HomeSections__SectionSomething"
        onChange={() => doSomething(id)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

Section.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imgUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Section;
```

So everytime I select an element from the array (click on the button), the parameter that goes to doSomething() inside the component's structure is always the first element instead of the one that is actually clicked.

I know that perhaps my code is kind of buggy and confusing but any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out that when I'm returning the component the input it's the same for all of the components, meaning that the first ID that the function doSomething finds is the first component ID. What I did by now is just placing a custom id to every input element but with proper coding I can reference just one single input for everyone of them If I bind the function in a different way.

```
return (
    <div className="SomethingSection__Container">
      <input
        className="hidden"
        type="file"
        id={`HomeSections__SectionSomething-${randomString}`}
        onChange={() => doSomething(id)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Section is passed the ID prop, so all of the functions declared inside of Section, already have access to the ID without needing it as an argument.

I think the problem is you have one too many arrow functions. This creates a reference which when executed now has stale data.

```
const doSomething = () => {
    console.log(id)
  }

...

onChange={doSomething}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: Well it may not solve your problem but it works. Functions declared inside of a component have access to its props, without needing to be explicitly passed.